# How to calculate: watts for AVR, VA (volt-ampere) for UPS

Tags: ups, pc

**I intend to buy an AVR or UPS, and I want to add a few external HDD's & a few Mini PC's.**

**I need to calculate how much power is used by every device so I don't overload the AVR or UPS**

### EXAMPLE: External HDD Charger data:

INPUT: 100-240V  ~50-60Hz  0.5A

OUTPUT: 12V  1.5A

### 1. How do I calculate watts for AVR (Automatic Voltage Regulator)?

Total devices W sum must be a bit under 600W for the AVR to work OK.

> Model LE600I - Maximum output power capacity: 600 W or 600 VA
>
> > DATA FOUND HERE
> >
> > > https://www.apc.com/shop/uk/en/products/Line-R-600VA-Automatic-Voltage-Regulator/P-LE600I
> > >
> > > > Documentation PDF: Automatic Voltage Regulator Line-R LE600I/LE1200I

V * A = W

Do I use 100V or 240V ?

100V * 0.5A = 50W -----> AVR 600W - 50W = 550W Remaining unused

240V * 0.5A = 120W ----> AVR 600W - 120W = 480W Remaining unused

?????

### 2. How do I calculate VA (Volt-ampere) for UPS 2200VA (Uninterruptible Power Supply)?

Total devices VA sum * 2 must be <= 2200VA for the UPS to work OK

V from OUTPUT * A from OUTPUT = VA ???

12V * 1.5A = 18W ??? ----> 2200VA / 2 - 18W = 1082VA Remaining unused

This is all the stuff I know now. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Neither. The 0.5 A is only an overestimation for compliance. Take your output power (12*1.5) and divide by say 0.7 for efficiency losses and low PF. Overall, VA rating is unlikely to be found on modern devices and you may need to calculate it if the power factor (PF) if known.

Comment: Thank you! Output 12V * 1.5A  / 0.7 = ~ 25.71 VA. Can use this only for electronics added UPS (2200VA) ?  or can I also use it for AVR since it also has a rating in VA (600VA) ?

Comment: Yes, that's a good approximation.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!